# AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, word-embedding

When I run my .py file containing the following code

```
if not os.path.exists('model_out'):
    model1 = gensim.models.Word2Vec(l, min_count = 1, size = 100, window = 5)
    model1.save('model_out')
model1.load('model_out')
model11 = gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.load(model1)
max_size = len(model.wv.vocab)-1
```

The following error is generated

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "assignment.py", line 35, in
>   
>       model11 = gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.load(model1)   File
>   "/Users/harshpanwar/Desktop/Enthire_assignment/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py",
>   line 1540, in load
>       model = super(WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)   File
>   "/Users/harshpanwar/Desktop/Enthire_assignment/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py",
>   line 228, in load
>       return super(BaseKeyedVectors, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)   File "/Users/harshpanwar/Desktop/Enthire_assignment/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py",
>   line 424, in load
>       compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)   File "/Users/harshpanwar/Desktop/Enthire_assignment/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py",
>   line 513, in _adapt_by_suffix
>       compress, suffix = (True, 'npz') if fname.endswith('.gz') or fname.endswith('.bz2') else (False, 'npy') AttributeError: 'Word2Vec'
>   object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: note: similar error occurs if passing a `Path()` object instead of a string to `model.save()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some functions might be deprecated. Try

```
from gensim import models
w = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('model', binary=True)
```

Or

```
from gensim import models
w = models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('model', binary=True)
```