# Azure blob storage model access for gensim in python

Tags: python, azure-storage, gensim

I am trying  to load my model files using below code

```
import gensim
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from smart_open import open

azure_storage_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=lnipcfdevlanding;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxx"
client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(azure_storage_connection_string)
file_prefix="azure://landing/TechnologyCluster/VectorCreation/embeddings/"
fin = open(file_prefix+"word2vec.Tobacco.fasttext.model", transport_params=dict(client=client))
clustering.embedding = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(fin)
```

But it is failing with below error
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'endswith'

I assume the way I  am passing file to  gensim.models.Word2Vec.load is not the right  way. I could not  find any good  example that how to pass  the filename  which is on Azure blob storage,  if I give complete uri it  does not work, what is the  right way to achieve  this  ?

Comment: code formatting is  not proper but do not know how to do   it  , so  please bear with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check :

**`AttributeError`** usually occurs when `save()` or `load()` function is called on an ***`object instance instead of class`*** as that is a class method..

Please note that the information in file can be  incomplete ,check if the binary tree is missing.In this case, the query may be obtained ,but you may not be able to continue with a **model** loaded with  this way.

> Check if the file path must be saved in `word2vec-format` file

binary is bool, if True, indicates data is in binary word2vec format.

**Note** from: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html.

Check if this way can be worked around by `importing` required models and by checking version compliance : -

`gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('model', binary=True)`

or with`KeyedVectors.load`  in place of   `.Word2Vec.load_...` according to what supports fasttext.

> Also check whether the model is correctly supports the
> function.

**References:**

1. [python - AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute
   'endswith' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59333165/attributeerror-word2vec-object-has-no-attribute-endswith)
2. [models.keyedvectors – Store and query word vectors — gensim
   (radimrehurek.com)](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#why-use-keyedvectors-instead-of-a-full-model)